# Image is not added / read in image upload field (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using eCom.Data;
using eCom.Models;
using IHostingEnvironment = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment;

namespace eCom.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private IHostingEnvironment _he;

        public ProductController(ApplicationDbContext db, IHostingEnvironment he)
        {
            _db = db;
            _he = he;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_db.Products.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).Include(f => f.SpecialTag).ToList());
        }

        //POST Index action method
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(decimal? lowAmount, decimal? largeAmount)
        {
            var products = _db.Products.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).Include(c => c.SpecialTag)
                .Where(c => c.Price >= lowAmount && c.Price <= largeAmount).ToList();
            if (lowAmount == null || largeAmount == null)
            {
                products = _db.Products.Include(c => c.ProductTypes).Include(c => c.SpecialTag).ToList();
            }
            return View(products);
        }

        //Get Create method
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["productTypeId"] = new SelectList(_db.ProductTypes.ToList(), "Id", "ProductType");
            ViewData["TagId"] = new SelectList(_db.SpecialTag.ToList(), "Id", "Tag");
            return View();
        }


        //Post Create method
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Products products, IFormFile image)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                /*var searchProduct = _db.Products.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Tag == products.Tag);
                if (searchProduct != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.message = "This product is already exist";
                    ViewData["productTypeId"] = new SelectList(_db.ProductTypes.ToList(), "Id", "ProductType");
                    ViewData["TagId"] = new SelectList(_db.SpecialTag.ToList(), "Id", "Tag");
                    return View(products);
                }*/

                if (image != null)
                {
                    var name = Path.Combine(_he.WebRootPath + "/Images", Path.GetFileName(image.FileName));
                    await image.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create));
                    products.Image = "Images/" + image.FileName;
                }

                /*if (image == null)
                {
                    products.Image = "Images/noimage.PNG";
                }*/
                _db.Products.Add(products);
                await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(products);
        }
```

I'm trying to make a website with asp.net. I'm a beginner. the theme of this website is the development of an online store with various products. everything went well until I had to create the first product (which, of course, also needs an image)
I don't get any errors from the compiler, I don't understand what the problem is. below is the specific piece of code for creating a new product.
after completing all the fields and adding an image click "save" and I receive this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZN2o.jpg
below is also the part of the Create View for Products

```
<h2 class="text-info">Add New Product</h2>
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="p-4 rounded border">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">

        </div>
        <h3>@ViewBag.message</h3>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Tag">Nume</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="Tag" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Tag" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="Price"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="GetImage("></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input asp-for="GetImage()" class="form-control" type="file" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="GetImage()" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: What you showed in the image is the create product form.   As it appears not to be bound to any model it will always show up as a blank form.  Its also not clear from your post if the file is saved or not.

Comment: @model eCom.Models.Products
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

is related to the Products model, sorry I didn't specify. what do you mean the file is not "saved"?

Comment: From what I understood from your code, the image file is saved to your file system.  Do you see the file that was added in your file system?

Comment: No, i cant, the image isnt in Image folder

Comment: Looking at your screenshot again your model is not valid. It requires a value in the image field, therefore your (Model.isvalid) == false.   I don't think your file input field is bound to the image property on your model.  I would first not make the image field required and then see how your code runs as it handles an empty image field anyway.

Comment: Understand, i will try, thanks